# SPARQL query help needed for DBpedia all programming language details

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

This is the query I am running to get these details of All programming languages.Every programming language has some influenced other languages or influenced by other language. So there may be many languages in influenced or influenced by. Now the prob is when it is printing all the values of it prints every values separately in rows. You can look into the picture. I want all its influenced or influencedBy programming languages in a single row. Query is below.

```
SELECT ?pl ?abstract ?influenced ?influencedBy
    WHERE { 
        ?pl dbo:abstract ?abstract .
            ?pl dbo:influenced ?influenced .
            ?pl dbo:influencedBy ?influencedBy .
            ?pl rdf:type dbo:ProgrammingLanguage .
            FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en') .
          }
```

**Screen shot of my result**
[image: Screen shot of my result]

You can see that This language has two influencedBy values and it is printing them in separate rows.

**Website data example**
[image: Website data example]

Comment: grouping and aggregate function `group_concat` is the way to go: `SELECT ?pl ?abstract (group_concat(?_influenced; separator="; ") as ?influenced) (group_concat(?_influencedBy; separator="; ") as ?influencedBy) WHERE {
 ?pl dbo:abstract ?abstract . 
?pl dbo:influenced ?_influenced . 
?pl dbo:influencedBy ?_influencedBy . 
?pl rdf:type dbo:ProgrammingLanguage . 
FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en') . 
}
group by ?pl ?abstract`

Comment: Hey @AKSW Thanks for your response and it works but the problem is, Now it just prints the links of them instead of their names!

Comment: what means the links? If you want a human-readable form, you have to query for English labels of the entities (`rdfs:label` property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AKSW said, something like --

```
SELECT                                                      ?pl 
                                                            ?abstract
       ( group_concat ( ?_influenced; separator="; " )   AS ?influenced )
       ( group_concat ( ?_influencedBy; separator="; " ) AS ?influencedBy ) 
WHERE
  { ?pl  dbo:abstract      ?abstract . 
    ?pl  dbo:influenced    ?_influenced . 
    ?pl  dbo:influencedBy  ?_influencedBy . 
    ?pl  rdf:type          dbo:ProgrammingLanguage . 
    FILTER ( LANG ( ?abstract ) = 'en' ) . 
  } 
GROUP BY ?pl ?abstract
```

### Edit to Add

To get the **`?pl_label`** (and I'm guessing, the **`?_influenced_label`** and **`?_influencedBy_label`**) you now say you want, you will need (and/or want) to tweak things a bit...

```
SELECT                                                            ?pl 
                                                                  ?pl_label
       ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influenced_label; separator="; " )   AS ?influenced )
       ( group_concat ( DISTINCT ?_influencedBy_label; separator="; " ) AS ?influencedBy ) 
                                                                  ?abstract
WHERE
  { ?pl             rdf:type          dbo:ProgrammingLanguage .
    ?pl             dbo:abstract      ?abstract . 
                    FILTER ( LANG ( ?abstract ) = 'en' ) 
    ?pl             rdfs:label         ?pl_label
                    FILTER ( LANG ( ?pl_label ) = 'en' ) .
    ?pl             dbo:influenced    ?_influenced . 
    ?_influenced    rdfs:label         ?_influenced_label
                    FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influenced_label ) = 'en' ) .
    ?pl             dbo:influencedBy  ?_influencedBy . 
    ?_influencedBy  rdfs:label         ?_influencedBy_label
                    FILTER ( LANG ( ?_influencedBy_label ) = 'en' ) .
          } 
GROUP BY ?pl ?pl_label ?abstract
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and it works but the problem is, Now it just prints the links of them instead of their names!

Comment: @ShajedulIslamAny what means the links? If you want a human-readable form, you have to query for English labels of the entities (`rdfs:label` property)

Comment: Worked but if I write query for pl_label and abstract only then I get 1949 results and If I write query with group_concat for influenced and influencedBy following your query then I get only 149 results. Can you tell me why is that? Is it happens when there is empty fields!

Comment: @ShajedulIslamAny Please show the query which doesn't work

Comment: @AKSW I am talking about the query that given by TallTed. It works but the problem as I said, If you just query for pl_label and abstract there are 1949 results and if you query for pl_label, abstract, influenced and influenced by then there are 149 results. May be it happened because these programming languages do not have influenced or influenced by values. But I want them all. Is there any query so that it ignores null values. Because of null values in influenced or in influenced by, It also ignores to take values of pl_label, abstract for that programming language and skip to the next.

Comment: Now I understand. `OPTIONAL` is the way to go. Put all the triple patterns for influenced and influencedBy **each in a separate** `OPTIONAL` clause such that you have two OPTIONAL patterns.