# Problem getting only programming languages from DBPedia using Sparql

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

Everything is working fine and yes I am getting programming languages using sparql query by java code but the problem is, you can look into the picture that sex_education is not a programming language but I am getting it into my result list. Not only this, but also some other results that are not programming languages. What can I do now to get only the programming languages !

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.*;

public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString(""
                + "prefix rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
                + "prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"
                + "PREFIX dbo:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"
                + "\n"
                + "SELECT ?pl ?label \n" + 
                "    WHERE { \n" + 
               // "          ?pl dbo:abstract ?abstract .\n" + 
                "            ?pl rdfs:label ?label .\n" + 
               // "            ?pl dbo:influenced ?influenced .\n" + 
               // "            ?pl dbo:influencedBy ?influencedBy .\n" + 
                "            ?pl rdf:type dbo:ProgrammingLanguage .\n" + 
               // "            FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en') .\n" + 
                                    "   FILTER (LANG(?label)='en')"+
                "         }");


        QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", qs.asQuery());

        ResultSet results = exec.execSelect();

        int count = 0;

        while (results.hasNext()) {

            System.out.println(results.next().get("label").toString()+"");
            //System.out.println(results.next().get("abstract").toString()+"\n\n");
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count);


        //ResultSetFormatter.out(results);
    }
}
```

#### Screen Shot of result

[image: Screen Shot of result]

Comment: Please do not post images but rather code and log messages in text instead.

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: And what is the question now? The query returns exactly the data that is contained in the dataset. Look at the DBpedia resource: http://dbpedia.org/page/Sex_education . The data types come either directly from the Wikipedia mappings or some heuristic (not sure whether those types are loaded). There is no infobox at the corresponding Wikipedia page though. As workaround, you could check for a discriminative property that could be used as filter, so check the entity and its properties and find one which a programming language never can have.

Comment: Note, data is neither sound nor complete here so will likely find missing facts or even wrong facts.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. There is another question I have asked related to dbpedia where you have replied. I need one more thing to know. can you please jump into it?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55279825/8038685

Comment: @ShajedulIslamAny what you call names, are labels in the dataset, thus, you have to query for the English `rdfs:label` values

Answer (score 0):

DBpedia data is dirty, just like the Wikipedia data from which DBpedia is derived.

DBpedia-Live (stalled at the moment, but meant to update in approximately real-time from the Wikipedia firehose) reflects Wikipedia changes faster than DBpedia (batch updated, usually 6-12 months between batches, usually 3-18 months behind Wikipedia changes).

You can copy-and-paste any query that runs on [the DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) to the [DBpedia-Live endpoint](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) to get results from the more recent data.