# DBpedia: Query some information about a specific person with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've been struggling to create a SPARQL query about one person.

Let's say for example, I want to have these informations for Aristotle :

- Birth Date
- Death Date
- Description (in English)

I have tried many things, but nothing working.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle>
        dbo:birthYear ?birth;
        dbo:deathYear ?death;
        dbo:abstract ?comment.
    FILTER (lang(?comment)='en')
}
LIMIT 10
```

I went to http://dbpedia.org/page/Aristotle and looked for the properties you requested. From experience, properties in the `dbo:` namespace are usually cleaner than the other namespaces. The rest is SPARQL 101.

(The birth and death dates are messy in this case. I don't think the dates are actually known, so the query returns just the year.)

Comment: That's perfect, thank you !! Do you know how I could retrieve all the names of the persons he has influenced ( `dbo:influenced` ) in a single field ?

Comment: @Arthur.Coruble use `group by` in combination with `group_concat` - by the way, this was asked and answered here several times, maybe you'll find the answer in a previous question. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279825/sparql-query-help-needed-for-dbpedia-all-programming-language-details) - and there are plenty of others for sure